# Using React.js and Material UI:"children" prop in modal container appearing behind modal while hard-coded text appears on modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using React v18 and Material UI v5.

I am trying to create a modal that can be accessed globally within my application. I inserted AppModal into App.tsx as shown here:

```
export default function App() {
    const { email } = useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <Box sx={root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Routes>
                            {/* TRUNCATED */}
            </Routes>
            <AppModal />
            <Toaster toastOptions={toast} />
        </Box>
    );
}
```

I've defined my ModalContextInterface as follows:

```
export interface ModalContextInterface {
    context: any;
    open: boolean;
    show: () => void;
    hide: () => void;
}
```

Created a ModalContext:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

import { ModalContextInterface } from "../types/interfaces";

const ModalContext = createContext<ModalContextInterface>(
    {} as ModalContextInterface
);

export default ModalContext;
```

which is then being used in AppModal:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";
import ModalContext from "src/contexts/ModalContext";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { modal_content } from "./ui.styles";

export default function AppModal({ children }: any) {
    const { context, open, hide } = useContext(ModalContext);
    return (
        <>
            {context ? (
                <>
                    {ReactDOM.createPortal(
                        <Modal
                            open={open}
                            onClose={hide}
                            style={{ backdropFilter: "blur(2px)" }}
                            slotProps={{
                                backdrop: {
                                    style: {
                                        backgroundColor: "#414141",
                                        opacity: "20%",
                                    },
                                },
                            }}
                        >
                            <Box sx={modal_content}>
                                {children}HARD CODED TEXT
                            </Box>
                        </Modal>,
                        context
                    )}
                </>
            ) : null}
        </>
    );
}
```

The `sx` styling for the `Box` that contains `children` and `HARD CODED TEXT` is as follows:

```
export const modal_content = {
    position: "absolute" as "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    opacity: "50%",
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: "black",
    borderRadius: "8px",
    boxShadow: "0 0 15px 0 #bbbbbb",
    color: "white",
    p: 5,
};
```

I am then using AppModal in my Logout component:

```
type Props = { open: boolean };
export default function Logout({ open: sidebarOpen }: Props) {
    const { show, open: modalOpen } = useContext(ModalContext);

    return (
        <ListItemButton sx={css.listItem} onClick={show}>
            <ListItemIcon
                sx={
                    sidebarOpen
                        ? { display: "flex" }
                        : { display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }
                }
            >
                <LogoutIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText
                sx={sidebarOpen ? { display: "flex" } : { display: "none" }}
                primaryTypographyProps={css.navText}
                primary="Logout"
            />
            {modalOpen && (
                <AppModal>
                    <LogoutContent />
                </AppModal>
            )}
        </ListItemButton>
    );
}
```

The issue I'm having is shown in the screenshot below:

[Screenshot of Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgGuZ.png)

I don't understand why `HARD CODED TEXT` is showing normally inside the modal but the text passed through the `children` prop somehow ends up behind the modal. `HARD CODED TEXT` is also duplicated behind the modal.

I've tried setting a div with `id='global-modal'` in `index.html` in the `public` folder and setting the container for ReactDOM.createPortal as document.getElementById('global-modal'). I've also tried setting the zIndex of the `Box` container containing the `Logout Component Content` text to 99999 but that didn't seem to do anything.

My goal is that I want to be able to nest a child component inside of AppModal anywhere within the app to render text, a form to submit something, or in this case, log out the user. I also need the ability to close the modal from within the modal, after hitting submit on a form, or a user hitting cancel.

Thanks for reading and any help would be greatly appreciated!